# flask db upgrade do not update to the latest version

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic, flask-migrate

I have Flask application with **Flask-Migrate==2.2.1**.

And I have issue with running **flask db upgrade** command.

Imagine that I have ten migrations (1-10)

Locally it works as should after running **flask db upgrade** it set head to the newest migration (10 in our case)
But on prodution the same command upgrade head only to 4 migration and get the next message:

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl MySQLImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade cd8a0199a8e7 -> 409302fd40b8, empty message
```

**In our case it is:  Running upgrade 2_migration -> 4_migration, empty message**

I'm quite noob in this topic, but I will be very thankful if you could help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Run `flask db history` on your production machine to see what the migration repository looks like. If it is not what you expect, then you have to figure out why your migration repository is different in that machine vs your local development system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fond the issue, it was my mistake on my side, thanks everyone